# bash oneliner to move *.ext files into a newly created directory

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a bash oneliner I can use to move *.css files into a newly created directory?

I have a structure like:

```
test_1:
    1.css
    2.css
    3.css

test_2:
    1.css
    2.css
    3.css
```

what i want to end up with is...

```
test_1:
    ids:
        1.css
        2.css
        3.css

test_2:
    ids:
        1.css
        2.css
        3.css
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 for dir in test_*
 do
     mkdir "$dir/ids"
     mv "$dir"/*.css "$dir/ids/"
 done
```

$

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you need a oneliner for the example than can be solved with a few lines. When you need to repeat similar calls on many places, introduce a function:

```
function movetosubdir {
   echo "Some code as given in other answers, perhaps use $1 and $2"
}

# Main code
# oneliner:
movetosubdir
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
mkdir test_1/ids test_2/ids; mv test_1/*.css test_1/ids; mv test_2/*.css test_2/ids
```